# Environment variables not used, even after reboot

Tags: windows-registry, environment-variables

I modified some environment variables (using both `setx` and through the GUI: Control Panel--System Properties--Advanced--Environment Variable). The changes persist after rebooting, which I can see in the terminals, in regedit or through the GUI. But they are not picked up by `powershell`, `cmd` or `gitbash`. Why would that be?

Here's some excerpts from powershell using the example environment variable `%HOMEDRIVE%`, run immediately after rebooting:

```
PS H:\> Get-ItemProperty Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment\


AWP_LOCALE182      : en-us
HOMEDRIVE          : C:
...

PS H:\> Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

...
HOMEDRIVE              : C:
...

PS H:\> $Env:HOMEDRIVE
H:
```

`cmd` is very similar, except that the [scripts in the two answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w) do successfully update the environment variables in cmd, but not for powershell or gitbash.

I have administrator privileges, but it is a work machine, so some restrictions still apply.

Comment: `%homedrive%` is a special environment variable that reflects the current user’s homedrive as specified in Active Directory. You can’t change that. If you’re trying to set a variable, use a different name.

Comment: When I open powershell, cmd or gitbash, they start in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%. At the moment it is a location that I never use, so my first command is always `cd somewhere_useful`. I have never used Active Directory before - does that mean it's a setting that is managed by my network admins?

Comment: Yes. This is normal behavior.